# ImageButton "onClick" not called

Tags: imagebutton, android, android-button

In my `Activity` layout I have some `ImageButton`. They all work but one and I can't understand why `onClick` isn't triggered when I click on it. I really don't have any ideas...

**EDIT** There was some ancient forgotten code that was overriding my `OnClickListener` with an empty one...

This is my xml `Layout`

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/gameselect_button_home"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_home_selector" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/gameselect_button_opendir"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/gameselect_button_home"
        android:background="@null"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_opendir_selector" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/gameselect_button_refresh"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/gameselect_button_opendir"
        android:background="@null"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_refresh_selector" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/gameselect_button_refreshone"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/gameselect_button_refresh"
        android:background="@null"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_refreshone_selector" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/gameselect_button_settings"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/gameselect_button_refreshone"
        android:background="@null"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_settings_selector" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/gameselect_button_grid"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/gameselect_button_settings"
        android:background="@null"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_grid_selector" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/gameselect_button_list"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/gameselect_button_grid"
        android:background="@null"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_list_selector" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/gameselect_button_help"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/gameselect_button_list"
        android:background="@null"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_help_selector" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/gameselect_emu_spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/gameselect_button_help" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is the code called inside `onResume()`

```
helpBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.gameselect_button_help);
helpBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
```

While this is my simple `onClick`

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.gameselect_button_help) {
        Log.i("Click", "OK");
        showHelpDialog();
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you initialize the button in `onResume` ?

Comment: init the button in onCreateView()

Comment: @A.S. focus on something else, as i said the other buttons can be clicked without problems

Comment: fixed layout size could be causing something to be layed out on top of the imagebutton so that it cannot receive clicks.

Comment: @TristanBurnside even if the button state drawable changes?

Comment: It seems unlikely but the touch call hierarchy is quite complicated, so I can't say for sure.

Answer (score 1):

In your OnCreate() method use this example code.

Change the ID button for the one you use.

```
ImageButton helpBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.gameselect_button_refresh);

helpBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.i("CLICK", "click");    
    }
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Wow, there's something else then, just tested this code and worked. try changing the type from ImageButton to ImageView in the xml and java in my example.

Answer (score 1):

Put this code in onResume() method like this.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ImageButton textview = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.gameselect_button_help);
    textview.setOnClickListener(this);
    super.onResume();
}
```

you can show Toast on Click of ImageButton.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (v.getId() == R.id.gameselect_button_help) {
        Log.i("Click", "OK");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hello", 5000).show();

    }

}
```

Working perfectly my side.

Comment: So its other problem. Just try with toast. Does it display?

Comment: No, it doesn't display or log anything

Comment: Just comment all other ImageButton and try only with this. It can be worked. And if its works means in your xml file you haven't set your UI properly

Comment: Tried both programmatically and commenting xml, no results

Comment: Thanks to your suggestion I discovered that some old code was called after my activity code overriding the setOnClickListener..

Comment: Yes because at my side its works perfectly without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code called inside onCreate() and not in on onResume().

```
helpBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.gameselect_button_help);
helpBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Comment: This makes no difference

Comment: It is the part of android life cycle.After you click imagebutton the lifecycle onRresume() is affected.

Comment: This makes no difference, since the other buttons work properly and this doesn't, even if i put it in `onCreate`

Comment: Can you tell.Is it an activity on a fragment??

Comment: The class actually extends `FragmentActivity` but it's `Activity` and I only use it to call a `DialogFragment`